# pass iframe src from one html page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have two html webpages. One page has a 'div' named "iframe-content" .
When I click on the div, it should set the iframe src in the second html page.

Page 1:

```
<div class="iframe-content" onclick="passIframe()">
     //div which should set the iframe src on the other page on clicking
</div>
```

Page 2:

```
<iframe src="about:blank" id="native-iframe" width="450" height="180"scrolling="no">
      //The iframe which should obtain the source from the first page 
</iframe>
```

Whenever I click the "iframe-content" ,it should open the html page 2 and it should also set the "native-iframe" source as I wish.

Is there any efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can send the url as a query parameter and on page2, you can read and set it to the iframe. Something like this:

```
// Page1:
function passIframe() {
    var url = ""; // The url to pass
    window.location.href = "/page2.html?url=" + url;
}

// Page2:
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var src= getParameterByName("url");
$("iframe").attr("src", url);
```

Note: the `getParameterByName` is just a function to get the query string parameter from the URL. I copied this function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) Stackoverflow question, but there are many other solutions to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can set iframe src attribute to your desired url

```
$('iframe').attr('src', url)
```